# ArcGIS Pro : in Portal/My Groups, organise data by folder for authorized users

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-portal, catalog-pane

I want to give access to organised data to several users, in ArcGIS Pro, through the *Catalog Pane* -> *Portal* -> *My Groups*.

At the moment, when I visualize the *My Groups* tab, I can see all data layers in a random order and at the same level. However, we have a lot of data layers (several hundreds), and looking for a particular layer in one single folder is clearly non efficient. Here is a minimal example, without any folder :

[image]

The goal is to classify them in different folders (a folder per country at the first level, and then a subfolder per subject).

Is there a way to do this in ArcGIS Pro or Portal ?

I know there is a way to use tags, but this is not what we want with the users, we really wish to organise data by folders.